# RunWorkerAsync returns busy state

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm using a BackgroundWorker to fetch data and update my UI. The code it's pretty self explanatory. When I click connect it connects to CANbus, starts background worker which fetches data and updates UI, when I click disconnect it stops fetching data from CANbus.

It works only for first time, when I'm trying to connect for the second time I'm getting an exception at RunWorkerAsync call which is inside RunWorkerCompleted callback about BackgroundWorker being busy and it cannot process more than one task at once.

That's what I don't quite understand, I'm making new instance of BackgroundWorker on every connection and have no idea why it's busy.

Looking for advice - thanks.

```
    CANALHandle h;
    BackgroundWorker canWorker;

    private void bConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.h == 0) {
            this.h = CANAL.CANALOpen("ED000200; 500", CANAL.FLAG_NONE);

            canWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            canWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            canWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            canWorker.DoWork += (object s, DoWorkEventArgs ev) => {
                if (CANAL.CANALDataAvailable(this.h) > 0) {
                    CANALMSG msg;
                    CANALStatus st = CANAL.CANALReceive(this.h, out msg);
                    ev.Result = msg;
                }
            };
            canWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs ev) => {
                if (ev.Error != null) {

                } else if (ev.Result != null) {
                    CANALMSG msg = (CANALMSG)ev.Result;

                    if (msg.id > 0) {
                        textCanId.Text = msg.id.ToString("X");
                        textCanLength.Text = msg.count.ToString("X");
                        textCanByte0.Text = (msg.count >= 1) ? msg.data[0].ToString("X2") : "";
                        textCanByte1.Text = (msg.count >= 2) ? msg.data[1].ToString("X2") : "";
                        textCanByte2.Text = (msg.count >= 3) ? msg.data[2].ToString("X2") : "";
                        textCanByte3.Text = (msg.count >= 4) ? msg.data[3].ToString("X2") : "";
                        textCanByte4.Text = (msg.count >= 5) ? msg.data[4].ToString("X2") : "";
                        textCanByte5.Text = (msg.count >= 6) ? msg.data[5].ToString("X2") : "";
                        textCanByte6.Text = (msg.count >= 7) ? msg.data[6].ToString("X2") : "";
                        textCanByte7.Text = (msg.count >= 8) ? msg.data[7].ToString("X2") : "";
                    }
                }
                canWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            };

            canWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void bDisconnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.h > 0) {
            canWorker.CancelAsync();
            canWorker.Dispose();
            CANAL.CANALClose(this.h);
            this.h = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You declare `WorkerSupportsCancellation = true`, but never check for `CancellationPending` from inside of `DoWork`, so your `CancelAsync()` might in fact do nothing. Your `RunWorkerCompleted` is a lambda, and as any lambda it is closed over the `canWorker` variable itself, as opposed to its current value. So it's plausible that your previous non-cancelled instance executes `canWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` on the current instance. Correctly handle `CancellationPending` from `DoWork`, and use `(BackgroundWorker)s` instead of `canWorker` from `RunWorkerCompleted`.

Comment: The Disconnect button's Click event handler does not actually stop the worker.  Something you probably already discovered by not dealing with e.Error.  So now it is a threading race with two workers running when you click Connect again, the completion of the existing worker tries to start the second worker again.  Fix it with a bool StopRequested variable, set it to true in Disconnect.